# Parametric tests for bootstrapped means

Tags: t-test, bootstrap

How can I compare two sets of bootstrap means, each with sample size $n = 500$? Can I apply a t-test?

Comment: What is the purpose of the comparison?

Comment: I have determined 500 ROC-AUC values in an out-of-sample bootstrapping for different models. Instead of comparing the averaged ROC-AUC (from the averaged predictions per sample) with a DeLong test, I want to show that there are differences in the distribution of ROC-AUCs between the models. I have thought about this for a long time and I am not sure if a t-test is sufficient, since I am not comparing the samples but a set of ROC-AUCs.

Comment: More specifically, what is your hypothesis / research question?

Comment: Is there a difference in the mean values of multiple samples from two groups taken by bootstrapping?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, you can compare the bootstrap samples by means of a $t$-test. But, since the out-of-sample set is, I believe, the same for all models, you have paired data so the correct test would be the paired $t$-test or its non-parametric variants such as the Mann-Whitney test.

Comment: I did this exactly the same way, but I noticed that with omcreasing n in bootstrap the p value gets smaller. That should not be then or?

Comment: it's ok for the p-value to go down as n goes high, this is how hyp. testing works; Here you can only tell they are not statistically equal. Perhaps another thing is to measure the difference between the two methods ad ask if that is relevant from a practical perspective.

Comment: However, the problem then is that by selecting the repetitions in the bootstrap, I can influence the p-value myself as a researcher. This would lead to taking a high n if possible in order to obtain significant p-values. Isn't there a test that is robust against this?

Comment: You cant increase the sample to infinity anyway since the original sample is finite. Anyway, by increasing the sample you are able to find differences provided there are any.